# program executes multiple times but doesn't update log file properly

Tags: python, logging

I'm having a bit of trouble with my log file for this script. When I start my script up, the first log file populates correctly. No issues. This script pretty much runs continuously since it uses rabbitmq and acts as a consumer. (it pulls a message off a queue, runs, and then waits to repeat) The issue is when the script runs a second or third, etc. time, the log file is the same as the first test even though it should be different.

To summarize, I am running some tests and using rabbitmq to distribute the proper tests to the right consumer. The consumer (the pc that has this script on it) runs every time it receives a message. The code's main purpose is to execute a tool(like nmap) and then package results. I'm assuming the issue is likely with how I have my logger set up so for those reading, don't get too caught up on what the tool is doing. Log related or shutil.copy is probably the issue but I'm not sure what's wrong about it. Here is the simplified code.

```
import os
import subprocess
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import logging.config
import shutil
import zipfile
import yaml


TOOL = 'nmap'
LOGGER_NAME = 'nmap-Run'

logger = None


class Tool(object):
    ''' class for test execution'''

    def __init__(self):
        ToolDefault.__init__(self, tool=TOOL)

    def _execute_tool(self):
        ''' Execute test based on associated yaml'''

        logging.config.fileConfig('C:\\Users\\cschu\\Documents\\Sec\\src\\config\\test_log.conf')
        global logger
        logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
        logger.info('Retrieving options')
        options = literal_eval(self.options)

        split_string = ['some', 'command', 'here']

        try:
            cmd_line_process = subprocess.Popen(split_string,
                                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            process_output, process_error = cmd_line_process.communicate()
            logger.info(process_output)
        except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as e:
            logger.info('An exception occurred: ', str(e))
            logger.info('Test failed')

        else:
            logger.info('Test has concluded')

    def _package_report(self):
        ''' Find latest test results and zip into local directory folder results.zip

        '''

        logger.info('Finding most recent test results')

        # do some work in a directory here looking for latest file with strftime
        upload_path = r"C:\test\resultFolder"

        logger.debug('Most recent test result is ' + upload_path)
        try:
            shutil.copy(r'C:\Users\cschu\Documents\Sec\src\Logg.log', upload_path)
        except IOError as e:
            pass

        # do work to zip upload_path which has Logg.log copied to it 
        # zip folder is called results.zip in local dir
        return r'C:\Users\cschu\Documents\Sec\src\results.zip'


def main():
    ''' 
    Do some work with rabbitmq and run the test based off rabbitmq message. 
    '''
    tool_object = Tool()
    rabbit_connection = RabbitConnection(tool_object)
    rabbit_connection.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is my test_log.conf file.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(os.getenv('LOG_FILE_PATH'), 'w')
# LOG_FILE_PATH is 'C:\Users\cschu\Documents\Sec\src\Logg.log'

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

So pretty much, a zipped folder is being returned with the contents of the test and and the log file. That log file is always the same as the first test even though it should be different. Does anyone see any issues with how my script is initializing the config file or something of the sort? I'd imagine that's the issue.

Comment: Maybe only one of them has the lock on the log file, the others can not access it, that's why you only see the first one.
Maybe they run In reverse order and you only see the last one.
Are all of them writing to the same file? Try changing the log file to be specific to each test.

Comment: All of the tests are writing to the same log file. The tests never run at the same time though. They are always sequential. I don't think a lock would make sense here. I may try creating multiple log files with datetime now. I guess I'll just have to move my fileHandler to my script instead of my logging config file and move the newly created log file to the zipped folder each time

Comment: If they are all writing to the same file, are you sure you are opening it in append mode? I suspect the issue is they are either locking the file or overwriting it. Check what happens when each file has a different name, that should give you the answer

Comment: it's write mode. Take a look at my fileHandler in my config file. I want the file to be overwritten with the results of the new test. Not appended

Comment: Why the Except IOError? That might be shadowing your bug were you getting any error there before?

Comment: I was not getting any errors however I could be. I will take a look